# Pass values from script to Java code and back in jsp file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am wondering how can I pass string (for example) from javascript code to Java code and back in jsp. For example: I want to hash password before send it to server. I am using html form. So I can write onsubmit function on the form(I know this function can be javasript function). In this function I will find the password field and I want to use Java code to hash it and after that I will change it. So I want to get password from the javascript code and to use it in java code and after that to use hashed password in the javascript code. How can I achieve that?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you want to invoke a server-side Java method from browser client-side JavaScript, then you likely want to make an Ajax call. Doing that can be made easier by using a library such as jQuery.

Comment: No, I want to hash password in client, because I use http, not https, so I don't want to send it in plain text. So I have something like this:
`<form .. onsubmit="hash()" > ... </form>` and I want in my hash function to have: `var t =
                <%=CryptUtil.hashpw(password, someSalt)%>`, but I cannot get password in this java code (I should get in from form element). 
I hope I explain it well.

Comment: `<%=` executes on the *server*, not the client, in order to render the output to send to the client. You are confusing where what runs. `CryptUtil` doesn't even exist in the client.